# What is the initial source address used by a DHCPv6 client when DHCP is used for address assignment?

Tags: ip, dhcp, ipv6, ip-address

When [DHCPv6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8415) is used for address assigment (determined by the M-Flag of a [NDP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861) Router Advertisment Message) the host obviously does not have a valid link-local address yet.

For [Stateless Address Autoconfiguration](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862) it is specified that the host sends the initial Neighbor Solicitation Message with the IPv6 unspecified address (::) as the source address ([RFC 4862 - Section 5.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862#section-5.4.2)).

DHCPv6 however does not specify any initial address to be used. It just specifies that the client must have an address when it sends it DHCP message directly to a server using an unicast address ([RFC 8415 - Section 17.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8415#section-17.1))

So...

#### 1. So what is the initial source address of the host/client when DHCPv6 is used for address assignment? Is it the unspecified address?

#### 2. If it is the unspecified address, is it specified somewhere that the source address automatically must be the unspecified address when no source address exists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You state

> the host obviously does not have a valid link-local address yet.

But that's not true.

RFC8415 for DHCPv6 [tells](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8415#section-5):

> The client uses a **link-local address or addresses determined
> through other mechanisms** for transmitting and receiving DHCP
> messages.

So the logical method is to:

- Have stateless address autoconfiguration create a valid link-local address ([Creation of Link-Local Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862#section-5.3)) (or provide an address "determined through other mechanisms"),
- use this address as source in DHCPv6 messages

To support this stance (which you apparently dismissed), here are other informations from RFC8415:

[3. Background](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8415#section-3):

> Two advantages of IPv6 are that support for multicast is required and
> **nodes can create link-local addresses during initialization**.  The
> availability of these features means that **a client can use its
> link-local address** and a well-known multicast address to discover and
> communicate with DHCP servers or relay agents on its link.

[4.1 IPv6 Terminology](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8415#section-4.1):

> link-local address
>
> An IPv6 address having a link-only scope, indicated by having the
> prefix (fe80::/10), that can be used to reach neighboring nodes
> attached to the same link.  **Every IPv6 interface on which DHCPv6 can
> reasonably be useful has a link-local address**.

Comment: Thanks, i really missed some info in the RFC... Do you know, if it is somewhere documented that stateless address autoconfiguration is used to create the link-local address even when the M-Flag of a Router Advertisement is not set? Or is it just the way Address Configuration is implemented in Operating Systems?

Comment: it's the way it's implemented, but I can talk only about what I know: Linux. as soon as your interface is up you get a link local ipv6. If you then connect this interface (a carrier is detected), it gets revalidated etc (as described in my link for "Creation of Link-Local Addresses")

Comment: and last: don't confuse [Creation of Link-Local Addresses](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4862#section-5.3) with [Creation of Global Addresses](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4862#section-5.5): this last one depends on router sollicitation etc and is probably disabled when using DHCPv6

Comment: @goulashsoup A router is not even necessary for a host to generate its own link-local address. The host could have such an address long before it ever bothered to look for a router, or even if there was no router at all.

Comment: @MichaelHampton When you only consider the generation of such a link-local address you are right, but according to [RFC 4862 - Stateless Address Autoconfiguration](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4862#section-5.4) such an address is "tentative" and packets send to it should be discarded  (_Other packets addressed to the tentative address should be silently discarded._) and the host should not use it as a source address. But of course you might have in mind another RFC which allows the use of a "tentative" (not confirmed) address (accepting/sending messages with it)...

Comment: @goulashsoup read a paragraph above. As I said, the address gets revalidated with carrier detect gets UP: I really meant DAD is triggered. Once DAD is over (3s?) then it's not tentative anymore. DHCPv6 will maybe have to wait DAD has been done. And btw, same for DHCPv6: DAD MUST be done on received addresses, as stated in the DHCPv6 RFC.

Comment: @A.B Thanks, of course, as i understand DAD does not require a router to be present to be successful...

Comment: DAD is in no way related to a router. It's related to checking one's IP is unique on the LAN

Comment: @A.B Thanks again, i expressed badly. Do you also know what the [initial Identity Association Options of a host is when DHCPv6 is used to assign a global address](https://superuser.com/questions/1529494/when-dhcpv6-is-used-in-a-home-network-what-is-the-initial-identity-association-r)?